# how to change the color of the font without triggering a:visited

Tags: html, css

So right now I have the following HTML and CSS

```
<div id = "navi">
            <ul>
                <li><a id = "topLinks" class = "currentPage" href = "index.html"> Home </a></li>
                <li><a id = "topLinks" href = "blockOne.html"> Read </a></li>
                <li> Write </li>
                <li> Vote </li>
                <li> Donate </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#topLinks:hover, #topLinks:active{
color: black;   
}

.currentPage{   

color:#ce5438;
font-size: 40px;
}
```

The problem is that if I current have my website on Home, the color for Home will be black (what I wanted), but if i then click on Read, the link for home will become a blue-ish color instead of return back to white. I tried to setting a:visited to white, but then it'll just change all links that I've visited to white regardless whether I'm on a page or not (no black font color on current page).

Help please?

Comment: ID's need to be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll just want to target the links within your navigation:

```
#navi a.currentPage {
    color: #000;
}

#navi a:visited {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: wow this is amazing. Not only did you fix my problem but also add the concept that current page can not be black no matter, which is really neat. thanks !